# Do character classes count as groups in regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

A small project I got assigned is supposed to extract website URLs from given text. Here's how the most relevant portion of it looks like :

```
webURLregex = re.compile(r'''(
   (https://|http://)
   [a-zA-Z0-9.%+-\\/_]+
   )''',re.VERBOSE)
```

This does do its job properly, but I noticed that it also includes the ','s and '.' in URL strings it prints. **So my first question is, how do I make it exclude any punctuation symbols in the end of the string it detects ?**

My second question is referring to the title itself ( finally ), but doesn't really seem to affect this particular program I'm working on : **Do character classes ( in this case [a-zA-Z0-9.%+-\/_]+ ) count as groups ( group[3] in this case ) ?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a couple example strings and what the result is? Character classes are things like `\w` and `\s`. Things in square brackets are sets and things with dashes like `a-z` are ranges. You've got outer parens making your whole match a capture group, and then an inner group for https, etc.. Seems odd to me. You could `(?:https://|http://)([a-zA-Z0-9.%+-\\/_]+)` for a non-capture group for the http part and a capture group for the rest.

Comment: But in the end, URLs are notoriously difficult to parse with a single regex. Each part follows different rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude some symbols at the end of string you can use **negative lookbehind**. For example, to disallow `. ,`:

```
.*(?<![.,])$
```

Answer (score 1):

answering in reverse:
No, character classes are just shorthand for bracketed text. They don't provide groups in the same way that surrounding with parenthesis would. They *only* allow the regular expression engine to select the specified characters -- nothing more, nothing less.

With regards to finding comma and dot: Actually, I see the problem here, though the below may still be valuable, so I'll leave it. Essentially, you have this: `[a-zA-Z0-9.%+-\\/_]+` the `-` character has special meaning: everything between these two characters -- by ascii code. so `[A-a]` is a valid range. It include A-Z, but also a bunch of other characters that aren't A-Z. If you want to include - in the range, then it needs to be the *last* character: `[a-zA-Z0-9.%+\\/_-]+` should work

---

For comma, I actually don't see it represented in your regex, so I can't comment specifically on that. It shouldn't be allowed anywhere in the url. In general though, you'll just want to add more groups/more conditions.

First, break apart the url into the specifc groups you'll want:
(scheme)://(domain)(endpoint)

Each section gets a different set of requirements: e.g. maybe domain needs to end with a slash:
`[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.com/` should match any domain that uses an alphanumeric character, and ends -- specifically -- with .com (note the `\.`, otherwise it'll capture any single character followed by `com/`

For the endpoint section, you'll probably still want to allow special characters, but if you're confident you don't want the url to end with, say, a dot, then you could do something `[A-Za-z0-9]` -- note the lack of a dot here, plus, it's length -- only a single character. This will change the rest of your regex, so you need to think about that.

A couple of random thoughts:

1. If you're confident you want to match the whole line, add a `$` to the end of the regex, to signify the end of the line. One possibility here is that your regex does match some portion of the text, but ignores the junk at the end, since you didn't say to read the whole line.
2. Regexes get complicated really fast -- they're kind of write-only code. Add some comments to help. E.g.

```
web_url_regex = re.compile(
  r'(http://|https://)'  # Capture the scheme name
  r'([a-zA-Z0-9.%+-\\/_])' # Everything else, apparently
)
```

3. Do not try to be exhaustive in your validation -- as noted, urls are hard to validate because you can't know for sure that one is valid. But the form is pretty consistent, as laid out above: scheme, domain, endpoint (and query string)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second question first, no a character class is not a group (unless you explicitly make it into one by putting it in parentheses).

Regarding the first question of how to make it exclude the punctuation symbols at the end, the code below should answer that.

Firstly though, your regex had an issue separate from the fact that it was matching the final punctuation, namely that the last `-` does not appear to be intended as defining a range of characters (see footnote below re why I believe this to be the case), but was doing so.  I've moved it to the end of the character class to avoid this problem.

Now a character class to match the final character is added at the end of the regexp, which is the same as the previous character class except that it does not include `.` (other punctuation is now already not included).  So the matched pattern cannot end in `.`.  The `+` (one or more) on the previous character class is now reduced to `*` (zero or more).

If for any reason the exact set of characters matched needs tweaking, then the same principle can still be employed: match a single character at the end from a reduced set of possibilities, preceded by any number of characters from a wider set which includes characters that are permitted to be included but not at the end.

```
import re

webURLregex = re.compile(r'''(
   (https://|http://)
   [a-zA-Z0-9.%+\\/_-]*
   [a-zA-Z0-9%+\\/_-]
   )''',re.VERBOSE)

str = "... at http://www.google.com/. It says"

m = re.search(webURLregex, str)

if m:
    print(m.group())
```

Outputs:

```
http://www.google.com/
```

[*] *The observation that the second `-` does not appear to be intended to define a character range is based on the fact that, if it was, such a range would be from 056-134 (octal) which would include also the alphabetical characters, making the `a-zA-Z` redundant.*

Comment: dots don't need to be escaped in ranges. They do need to be escaped outside of ranges. As far as I recall, the only thing that needs to be escaped in a range is the end-range character `]`. (but escaping doesn't hurt either)

Comment: Thank you, but isn't negative lookbehind a lot simpler ? I just added (?<![.,]) and it works properly.

Comment: @WilliamFrog8 I think I read somewhere that lookahead/behind is expensive, though maybe this isn't a concern for your use case.

Comment: @WilliamFrog8 Someone seems to think so at least (see https://github.com/apigee/apigeelint/issues/54 though I can't remember where I read it previously)

Comment: Thank you so much !

I am fairly new to coding so the programs I make hardly require optimization of that sort, but it is good to know either way.

Comment: @WilliamFrog8 You're certainly right that the look-behind is more readable, so for that reason, yes I think you're right, it would be better as a starting point than my regex. Just worth bearing in mind that this issue would be something to consider if you later find that it is in an inner loop that you have to optimise.